# Looking for ways to optimize DB2 query

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

I have a DB2 query as below. I am looking for ways to improve the speed of this one. I have tried visual explain but no indexes were advised by the index advisor. Can somebody have a look at this and advise if something can be done?

There is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW PSCMPORDVW
    AS
    WITH INPROGRESS AS
     (
     SELECT
     DIODR#
     , DIDISP
     , DIUNIT
     , DISTST
     , DIAPRV
     , DIETAD
     , DITRLR AS TRAILER_ID
     , DIDR1
     , DIETAT
     FROM
     LOAD
     WHERE
     DIETAD <> 0
     AND DIETAT <> '0000'
     ORDER BY
     1
     )
    , STOPGROUP AS
     (
     SELECT
     SOORD STOPORDER
     , COUNT(*) STOPSREMAIN
     , MIN(SOSTP#) NEXTSTOP
     , MAX(SOAPPR) APPTREQ
     FROM
     STOPOFF
     INNER JOIN
     INPROGRESS
     ON
     DIODR# = SOORD
     WHERE
     SOARDT = 0
     GROUP BY
     SOORD
     ORDER BY
     1
     )
    , STOPAPPTS AS
     (
     SELECT
     SOORD APPTORDER
     , SOCUST STOPCUST
     , SOEDA ETADATE
     , SOETA ETATIME
     , SOADT1 EARLYDATE
     , SOATM1 EARLYTIME
     , SOADT2 LATEDATE
     , SOATM2 LATETIME
     , SOCTYC NEXTCITY
     , SOSTP# APPTSTOP
     , SOST NEXTSTATE
     FROM
     STOPOFF
     INNER JOIN
     STOPGROUP
     ON
     STOPORDER = SOORD
     AND NEXTSTOP = SOSTP#
     )
    SELECT
     ORDER_NUMBER
    , SHIPPER_ID
    , SHIPPER_NAME
    , SHIPPER_ADDRESS_1
    , SHIPPER_ADDRESS_2
    , SHIPPER_CITY
    , SHIPPER_ST
    , SHIPPER_ZIP
    , SHIPPER_ZIP_EXT
    , LOAD_AT_ID
    , LOAD_AT_NAME
    , LOAD_AT_ADDRESS_1
    , LOAD_AT_ADDRESS_2
    , LOAD_AT_CITY
    , LOAD_AT_ST
    , LOAD_AT_ZIP
    , LOAD_AT_ZIP_EXT
    , LOAD_AT_LATITUDE
    , LOAD_AT_LONGITUDE
    , EARLY_PU_DATE_TIME
    , LATE_PU_DATE_TIME
    , EARLY_DELV_DATE_TIME
    , EST_REVENUE
    , ORDER_DIV
    , CONSIGNEE_ID
    , CONSIGNEE_NAME
    , CONSIGNEE_ADDRESS_1
    , CONSIGNEE_ADDRESS_2
    , CONSIGNEE_CITY
    , CONSIGNEE_ST
    , CONSIGNEE_ZIP
    , CONSIGNEE_ZIP_EXT
    , CONSIGNEE_LATITUDE
    , CONSIGNEE_LONGITUDE
    , TRAILER_TYPE
    , ORDER_MESSAGE
    , ADDITIONAL_STOPS
    , CMDTY_CODE
    , CMDTY_DESCRIPTION
    , ORDER_MILES
    , ORDER_WGT
    , ORIGIN_CITY_CODE
    , ORIGIN_CITY
    , ORIGIN_ST
    , DEST_CITY_CODE
    , DEST_CITY_NAME
    , DEST_ST
    , PICK_UP_AREA
    , PLAN_INFO
    , NUMBER_LDS
    , NUMBER_DISP
    , SHIP_DATE_TIME
    , NEW_PICKUP_AREA
    , EQUIPMENT_NUMBER
    , APPT_REQ
    , APPT_MADE
    , PRE_T_SEQ
    , PRE_T_AREA
    , LOAD_DISPATCHED
    , CUST_SERV_REP
    , NEGOTIATIONS
    ,
     (
     CASE
     WHEN UNUNIT IS NOT NULL
     THEN UNUNIT
     ELSE ' '
     END
     )
     UNIT_DISPATCHED
    ,
     (
     CASE
     WHEN UNSUPR IS NOT NULL
     THEN UNSUPR
     ELSE ' '
     END
     )
     DRIVER_MGR_CODE
    , COALESCE(SUPNAM, ' ') DRIVER_MGR_NAME
    ,
     (
     CASE
     WHEN UNFMGR IS NOT NULL
     THEN UNFMGR
     ELSE ' '
     END
     )
     FLEET_MGR_CODE
    , COALESCE(FLTNAM, ' ') FLEET_MGR_NAME
    ,
     (
     CASE
     WHEN UNTRL1 IS NOT NULL
     THEN UNTRL1
     ELSE ' '
     END
     )
     TRAILER_ID
    , DIDISP DISPATCH_NUMBER
    , (COALESCE(BCMCNEW, ' ')) FED_MC_ID
    , DIUNIT DISPATCHED_UNIT
    , CASE
     WHEN UNETAD <> 0
     AND UNETAT = ''
     THEN CVTDATETIM(CHAR(UNETAD),'0000', (
     SELECT
     SUBSTR(DATA_AREA_VALUE, 1109, 2) AS TIMEZONE
     FROM
     TABLE(QSYS2.DATA_AREA_INFO('COMPAN', '*LIBL'))
     )
     )
     WHEN UNETAD <> 0
     THEN CVTDATETIM(CHAR(UNETAD),UNETAT, (
     SELECT
     SUBSTR(DATA_AREA_VALUE, 1109, 2) AS TIMEZONE
     FROM
     TABLE(QSYS2.DATA_AREA_INFO('COMPAN', '*LIBL'))
     )
     )
     WHEN UNETAD = 0
     THEN '0000-00-00T00:00:00-00:00'
     END AS ETA_DATE_TIME
    , NEXTSTOP
    , CASE
     WHEN SOARDT <> 0
     AND SOARTM = ''
     THEN CVTDATETIM(CHAR(SOARDT),'0000', (
     SELECT
     SUBSTR(DATA_AREA_VALUE, 1109, 2) AS TIMEZONE
     FROM
     TABLE(QSYS2.DATA_AREA_INFO('COMPAN', '*LIBL'))
     )
     )
     WHEN SOARDT <> 0
     THEN CVTDATETIM(CHAR(SOARDT),SOARTM, (
     SELECT
     SUBSTR(DATA_AREA_VALUE, 1109, 2) AS TIMEZONE
     FROM
     TABLE(QSYS2.DATA_AREA_INFO('COMPAN', '*LIBL'))
     )
     )
     WHEN SOARDT = 0
     THEN '0000-00-00T00:00:00-00:00'
     END AS STOP_ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME
    , CASE
     WHEN SOLUDT <> 0
     AND SOLUTM = ''
     THEN CVTDATETIM(CHAR(SOLUDT),'0000', (
     SELECT
     SUBSTR(DATA_AREA_VALUE, 1109, 2) AS TIMEZONE
     FROM
     TABLE(QSYS2.DATA_AREA_INFO('COMPAN', '*LIBL'))
     )
     )
     WHEN SOLUDT <> 0
     THEN CVTDATETIM(CHAR(SOLUDT),SOLUTM, (
     SELECT
     SUBSTR(DATA_AREA_VALUE, 1109, 2) AS TIMEZONE
     FROM
     TABLE(QSYS2.DATA_AREA_INFO('COMPAN', '*LIBL'))
     )
     )
     WHEN SOLUDT = 0
     THEN '0000-00-00T00:00:00-00:00'
     END AS STOP_DEPART_DATE_TIME
    , ORBAMT ORDER_INV_AMT
    , ORARST AR_STATUS_FLAG
    , DISTST SETTLEMENT_FLAG
    , DIAPRV APPROVED_FOR_PAY
    , BCCARR CARRIER_CODE
    , BCNAME CARRIER_NAME
    , BCADDR CARRIER_ADDRESS_1
    , BCADR2 CARRIER_ADDRESS_2
    , BCCITY CARRIER_CITY
    , BCST CARRIER_ST
    , BCZIP CARRIER_ZIP
    FROM
     INPROGRESS
     INNER JOIN
     PSMAINORVW A
     ON
     DIODR# = ORDER_NUMBER
     AND DIDISP = NUMBER_DISP
     AND
     (
     SUBSTR(ORDER_NUMBER, 1, 2) <> 'DH'
     AND SUBSTR(ORDER_NUMBER, 1, 1) <> 'M'
     )
     LEFT OUTER JOIN
     STOPOFF
     ON
     DIODR# = SOORD
     AND SOSTP# = 90
     LEFT OUTER JOIN
     LMCARR
     ON
     DIUNIT = BCCARR
     LEFT OUTER JOIN
     MMILES
     ON
     MMORD# = DIODR#
     AND MMRECTYPE = 'D'
     AND MMDSP# = DIDISP
     EXCEPTION JOIN
     ORDBILL B
     ON
     B.ORODR# = DIODR#
     AND B.ORSEQ = ' '
     AND ORARST = '1'
     LEFT OUTER JOIN
     STOPGROUP
     ON
     STOPORDER = DIODR#
     LEFT OUTER JOIN
     STOPAPPTS
     ON
     APPTORDER = STOPORDER
     AND APPTSTOP = NEXTSTOP
     LEFT OUTER JOIN
     UNITS
     ON
     UNUNIT = DIUNIT
     AND UNORD# = ORDER_NUMBER
     LEFT OUTER JOIN
     SUPMAST
     ON
     SUPCDE = UNSUPR
     LEFT OUTER JOIN
     FLTMAST
     ON
     UNFMGR = FLTCDE
    WHERE
     DIETAD <> 0
     AND DIETAT <> '0000'
    RCDFMT PSCMPORDVW ;
```

I suspect that the below part might be slowing it up. Can someone advise what can be done here?

```
 STOPGROUP AS
         (
         SELECT
         SOORD STOPORDER
         , COUNT(*) STOPSREMAIN
         , MIN(SOSTP#) NEXTSTOP
         , MAX(SOAPPR) APPTREQ
         FROM
         STOPOFF
         INNER JOIN
         INPROGRESS
         ON
         DIODR# = SOORD
         WHERE
         SOARDT = 0
         GROUP BY
         SOORD
         ORDER BY
         1
         )
```

Comment: it helps me to format the SQL clearly.  All tables get assigned an "as" letter. a, b, c. Then columns are qualified with the "as" letter.  select a.soord  from stopoff a join inprogress b .   That way I can better see which tables the columns come from.

Comment: when you run that 2nd query by itself, does it run slowly?

Comment: @RockBoro no not really

Answer (score 0):

Even though Visual Explain (VE) doesn't advise any indexes ... it can still be used to see how long various parts of your query are taking.

If the

```
 SELECT
 SOORD STOPORDER
 , COUNT(*) STOPSREMAIN
 , MIN(SOSTP#) NEXTSTOP
 , MAX(SOAPPR) APPTREQ
```

Turns out to really be any issue, I'd look at using an [Encoded Vector Index (EVI)  with aggregate values](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibmi/library/i-accelerated-analytics-db2-evi-tech/index.html) to speed that up.

I'd suggest breaking it down and building back up while using VE to see where the issues lie.

The only magic wand I might suggest is putting code into a user defined table function (UDTF); assuming you currently plan to use the view like so:

```
select *
from myview
where something = 'somevalue';
```

A UDTF would allow for you to explicitly push the selection into the query

```
select *
from table ( myudtf('somevalue'));
```